# Using jquery, How can i stick a textbox inside a div and have it be the first element in the div?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have this:

```
<div id="container"> 
      <span id=test></span>
      <span id=test2></span>
</div>
```

and I have a textbox somewhere else on the page

```
<input type="text" id='myTextbox" />
```

and I want to move the textbox so it shows up like this:

```
<div id="container"> 
     <input type="text" id='myTextbox" />
     <span id=test></span>
     <span id=test2></span>
</div>
```

I thought append would do it but that looks like it adds it to the end of the div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, fix your markup. You have single and double quotes in the following:

```
<input type="text" id='myTextbox" />
```

As for your question, use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$('#container').prepend($('#myTextbox'));
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qaV6/)

Fixed markup..

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="test"></span>
    <span id="test2"></span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="myTextbox" />
```

It's also worth noting that could use the [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element as opposed to an input element:

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#container').prepend('<input type="text" id="myTextbox" />').html();
```

Comment: This wouldn't prepend the existing `input` element, it would create another and duplicate the `id` (which is invalid).. http://jsfiddle.net/WQ8yV/